# Unable to resolve 271.0: missing requirement [271.0] package; (&(package =org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client)(version>=2.7.0)(!(version>=3.0.0)))

Tags: osgi, osgi-bundle, karaf

I am trying to install my bundle  and I get the following error:

```
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle horizon-util [271]: Unable to resolve 271.0: missing requirement [271.0] package; (&(package
=org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client)(version>=2.7.0)(!(version>=3.0.0)))
Bundle ID: 271
```

these are my bundles :

```
karaf@root> osgi:list
START LEVEL 100 , List Threshold: 50
   ID   State         Blueprint      Spring    Level  Name
[  45] [Active     ] [            ] [       ] [   50] geronimo-j2ee-management_1.1_spec (1.0.1)
[  46] [Active     ] [            ] [       ] [   50] Commons Collections (3.2.1)
[  47] [Active     ] [            ] [       ] [   50] Apache ServiceMix :: Bundles :: jasypt (1.9.0.1)
[  48] [Active     ] [            ] [       ] [   50] geronimo-jms_1.1_spec (1.1.1)
[  49] [Active     ] [            ] [       ] [   50] Commons Pool (1.6.0)
[  50] [Active     ] [            ] [       ] [   50] Apache ServiceMix :: Bundles :: xpp3 (1.1.0.4c_5)
[  51] [Active     ] [            ] [       ] [   50] Apache ServiceMix Bundles: dom4j-1.6.1 (1.6.1.2)
[  52] [Active     ] [            ] [       ] [   50] Commons Lang (2.6)
[  53] [Active     ] [            ] [       ] [   50] Apache ServiceMix Bundles: oro-2.0.8 (2.0.8.3)
[  54] [Active     ] [            ] [       ] [   50] Apache ServiceMix :: Specs :: Stax API 1.0 (1.9.0)
[  55] [Active     ] [            ] [       ] [   50] Apache ServiceMix Bundles: xstream-1.3 (1.3.0.3)
[  56] [Active     ] [            ] [       ] [   50] Apache ServiceMix :: Bundles :: jdom (1.1.0.4)
[  57] [Active     ] [            ] [       ] [   50] Apache ServiceMix :: Bundles :: velocity (1.7.0.4)
[  58] [Active     ] [            ] [       ] [   50] Apache Aries Transaction Manager (0.3.0)
[  59] [Active     ] [            ] [       ] [   50] kahadb (5.7.0)
[  60] [Active     ] [            ] [       ] [   50] activemq-pool (5.7.0)
[  61] [Active     ] [            ] [       ] [   50] activemq-console (5.7.0)
[  62] [Active     ] [            ] [       ] [   50] activemq-ra (5.7.0)
[  63] [Active     ] [Created     ] [       ] [   50] activemq-core (5.7.0)
                                       Fragments: 68
[  64] [Active     ] [Created     ] [       ] [   50] activemq-karaf (5.7.0)
[  65] [Active     ] [Created     ] [       ] [   50] Apache XBean :: OSGI Blueprint Namespace Handler (3.11.1)
[  66] [Active     ] [            ] [       ] [   50] Commons JEXL (2.0.1)
[  67] [Active     ] [            ] [       ] [   50] Apache ServiceMix :: Specs :: Scripting API 1.0 (1.9.0)
[  68] [Resolved   ] [            ] [       ] [   50] activemq-blueprint (5.7.0)
                                       Hosts: 63
[  69] [Active     ] [Created     ] [       ] [   50] activemq-broker.xml (0.0.0)
[  83] [Active     ] [            ] [       ] [   50] Joda-Time (1.6.2)
[  84] [Active     ] [            ] [       ] [   50] Apache XBean :: Spring (3.11.1)
[  85] [Active     ] [            ] [       ] [   50] activemq-spring (5.7.0)
[  99] [Active     ] [Created     ] [       ] [   50] camel-karaf-commands (2.10.7)
[ 100] [Active     ] [            ] [       ] [   50] camel-core (2.10.7)
[ 102] [Active     ] [            ] [       ] [   50] camel-spring (2.10.7)
[ 103] [Active     ] [Created     ] [       ] [   50] camel-blueprint (2.10.7)
[ 106] [Active     ] [            ] [       ] [   50] camel-jms (2.10.7)
[ 107] [Active     ] [            ] [       ] [   50] activemq-camel (5.7.0)
[ 172] [Active     ] [            ] [       ] [   50] Apache CXF Compatibility Bundle Jar (2.6.9)
[ 173] [Active     ] [Created     ] [       ] [   50] camel-cxf (2.10.7)
[ 174] [Active     ] [            ] [       ] [   50] camel-cxf-transport (2.10.7)
[ 181] [Resolved   ] [            ] [       ] [   80] simple-camel-blueprint.xml (0.0.0)
[ 182] [Active     ] [            ] [       ] [   50] camel-stream (2.10.7)
[ 188] [Installed  ] [            ] [       ] [   80] ERP-blueprint.xml (0.0.0)
[ 199] [Active     ] [            ] [       ] [   50] camel-sql (2.10.7)
[ 204] [Installed  ] [            ] [       ] [   80] horizon-core (0.0.1)
[ 206] [Active     ] [            ] [       ] [   50] Data mapper for Jackson JSON processor (1.9.10)
[ 207] [Active     ] [            ] [       ] [   50] Jackson JSON processor (1.9.10)
[ 208] [Active     ] [            ] [       ] [   50] camel-jackson (2.10.7)
[ 209] [Active     ] [            ] [       ] [   50] MongoDB Java Driver (2.11.2.RELEASE)
[ 259] [Installed  ] [            ] [       ] [   80] Spring Data MongoDB Support (1.3.3.RELEASE)
[ 269] [Installed  ] [            ] [       ] [   80] horizon-util (0.0.1)
```

Do I need to update Apache CXF to 2.7.0 version?
And how do I do that?
I tried to update the bundle but it did not work.

Thank you for any pointer

Answer (score 0):

your ***horizon-util*** bundle depends on bundle **org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client** with version greater than and equal to 2.7.0.
So try to install appropriate version to resolve the error.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I've installed Apache CXF without Camel so I will give you the steps for this scenario but maybe it will work the same way for Camel.
So, to remove the current version first you have to remove the repository:

```
feature:repo-list
   --> gives you the list of repositories (in my case cxf-2.x.x)

feature:repo-remove cxf-2.x.x
   --> removes the repository from Karaf

feature:repo-add mvn:org.apache.cxf.karaf/apache-cxf/2.7.10/xml/features
   --> Adds new version of CXF repository (in this case 2.7.0)

feature:install cxf-jaxrs
   --> Installs the part of CXF you need (or cxf instead of cxf-jaxrs if we need all)

feature:list | grep cxf
   --> shows a list of bundles related to CXF. [x] means that they are started
```

I hope this will help you.